# Concat on two values assigned by cidrsubnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I am trying to concat two lists of subnets into module.vpc.public_subnets

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  ...
  public_subnets = [
    concat(local.ext_a_subnets,local.ext_b_subnets)
  ]
  ...
}
...
locals {
  ...
  ext_a_subnets = [
    for num in range(length(local.azs)) :
    cidrsubnet(local.cidr, 8, num + 10)
  ]
  ext_b_subnets = [
    for num in range(length(local.azs)) :
    cidrsubnet(local.cidr, 8, num)
  ]
  ...
}
```

When I run `terraform validate`, I get the below error:

```
Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on main.tf line 45, in module "vpc":
  45:   public_subnets = [
  46:     concat(local.ext_a_subnets,local.ext_b_subnets)
  47:   ]

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "public_subnets"
defined at .terraform/modules/vpc/variables.tf:151,1-26: element 0: string
required.
```

However, putting the cidrsubnet for loop in module.vpc.public_subnets directly works fine:

```
  public_subnets = [
    for num in range(length(local.azs)) :
    cidrsubnet(local.cidr, 8, num + 10)
  ]
```

Is concat not the function I need? Pretty new to terraform so appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html) returns a list. So assuming that your `concat` actually works, it should be:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  ...
  public_subnets = concat(local.ext_a_subnets,local.ext_b_subnets)
  ...
}
```

Comment: So this is definitely the right answer and the config validates now, but now terraform apply is returning:

Error: Error creating ENI: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID '10.0.10.0/24' does not exist

Comment: Yep, I tried to upvote when I meant to accept. Will post another question re: subnets if I can't figure this out. Thank you again!!

Comment: @m-bers No problem. For upvoates I think you need a little bit more of reputation.